# Multiple master in ROS

Tags: ros, multimaster

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys!
I am looking for the solution to work with multiple master, for example I use one computer to get camera images adn robot status, another computer is connected with the previous computer through wifi and also connect with another camera, therefore in my opinion, I need to ros master to run this. Is that right?
P/S: I am programming with Qt C++

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198080/multiple-master-in-ros/) by [domikilo](https://answers.ros.org/users/8836/domikilo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2014-11-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You shouldn't need multiple ROS masters for this; you should be able to run the ROS master on one machine and have the nodes on the other machine use it.

You may find the [ROS on Multiple Machines tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines) helpful.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0